# Tonic.PHP on having "/resource" and "/resource/id" URL's

Tags: php, url, restful-url, tonic

I'm trying to get the URL "/videoGame" to run "listAllVideoGames" method and "/videoGame/#" (Where # is a number) to run "getVideoGame" method. Changing priorities with "@priority" annotation I can make both URL's call one or the other but can't find the way to do what I described.

```
/**
 * @uri /videoGame
 * @uri /videoGame/:id
 */
class VideoGame extends Resource{

    protected function getDao(){
        return new VideoGameDao();
    }

    /**
     * @uri /videoGame
     * @json
     * @provides application/json
     * @method GET
     */
    public function listAllVideoGames(){
        return new Response(Response::OK,$this->dao->getAllVideoGames());
    }

    /**
     * @uri /videoGame/:id
     * @json
     * @provides application/json
     * @method GET
     */
    public function getVideoGame($id){
        $vg = $this->dao->getVideoGame($id);
        if ($vg){
            return new Response(Response::OK,$vg);
        }else{
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to do this is to create a kind of dispatcher for the GET calls like this:

```
/**
 * @uri /videoGame
 * @uri /videoGame/:id
 */
class VideoGame extends Resource{

    protected function getDao(){
        return new VideoGameDao();
    }

    /**
     * @uri /videoGame/:id
     * @provides application/json
     * @method GET
     */
    public function getVideoGames($id = 0){
        if (is_numeric($id) && $id > 0){
            return $this->getVideoGame($id);
        }else{
            return $this->getAllVideoGames();
        }
    }

    private function getVideoGame($id){
        $vg = $this->dao->getVideoGame($id);
        if ($vg){
            return new Response(Response::OK,$vg);
        }else{
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public function getAllVideoGames(){
        return new Response(Response::OK,$this->dao->getAllVideoGames());
    }
```